# How can I call an instance method winthin a searchable Sunspot model block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, eval, sunspot

I have a Solr-indexed RoR model (via Sunspot).

How can I put a call to an instance method in the searchable block?

I want to do this:

```
searchable
  string :name
  self.address.each do |a|
    eval 'string :address_' + a.id.to_s do ' + a.value + ' end'
  end
end
```

How can I do this given that Sunspot redefines self in the DSL here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to index here?

Comment: I am trying to create multiple string fields in each document. Each document I am indexing has an associated set of addresses - and each address value should be indexed in a field named with the ID of that address.

Comment: Are you intending to do the search by passing in the **IDs** or the **values** of the addresses?

Comment: I want the name of the field to include the ID and the value to include the address itself.

Comment: It would be really useful if you could describe the problem you're trying to solve! What kind of values (related to addresses) are you hoping to search by?
You could always just index one field **addresses** with both **ID** and the **value** contained in it.

`string :addresses, :multiple => true do`

`addresses.map {|addr| "#{addr.id}, #{addr.value}"}`

`end`

Comment: That would work, but I want to sort on these values, and I think multivalue fields don't work for sorting.

Comment: Hmm.. which field are you trying to sort by? The value field of addresses?

Comment: Yes, the value of the field addresses.

Comment: I'm not sure you would be able to sort by it. You do have many-to-many relationships, which complicates this.